# Recent module, what is preferred rcheck or update?

Tags: iptables, ddos

Let's say I have the following rules:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -m recent --set --name counting1 --rsource 
iptables -A INPUT -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 2 --name counting1 --rsource -j LOG --log-prefix "SSH  ataque " 
iptables -A INPUT -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 2 --name counting1 --rsource -j RETURN 
-A INPUT -j ACCEPT
```

I have read the manual but I still don't understand exactly in what cases it's preferred either --rcheck or --update option... does update mean that the hitcount is reset to 0 and restart the (as in the above example) the 60 seconds?

Please bear in mind that these rules are only en example to expose this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the man page of iptables:

```
   [!] --rcheck
          Check if the source address of the packet is  currently  in  the
          list.

   [!] --update
          Like  --rcheck,  except it will update the "last seen" timestamp
          if it matches.
```

So, using `update` will not reset the hitcount, it will (re)set the last seen timestamp. The following is said about `--seconds`:

```
   --seconds seconds
          This  option must be used in conjunction with one of --rcheck or
          --update. When used, this will narrow the match to  only  happen
          when  the  address  is  in the list and was seen within the last
          given number of seconds.
```

That means using `--rcheck` makes the rule to match only the time interval scecified in the rule (e.g. with `--seconds`) at a time, while using `--update` will extend the time interval the rule is being matched if matching packets are encountered during the interval.

So, if there is a matching packet every 45 secs the example rules shown in the question will keep on logging the packets and returning from the chain. OTOH if `--rcheck` had been used, every second packet would not be matched (as the 60 sec interval for two matching packets has expired).

Answer (score 1):

Did not test that -- but looking at the [source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/34d4ddd359dbcdf6c5fb3f85a179243d7a1cb7f8/net/netfilter/xt_recent.c#L276), I would suspect the example to work this way:

1. `--set` adds the ip address and increases the hitcount ;
2. first "LOG" `--update` checks if hitcount is 2 or more *and increases it, if so* ;
3. next "RETURN" `--update` tests it again [and again increases it, if matched](https://lists.netfilter.org/pipermail/netfilter/2005-August/062450.html).

---

So for any new matching packet:

- if there were no hits before -- we pass, and hitcount gets increased to 1 ;
- if there was 1 recent hit -- we stop, and hitcount is increased by 3 and becomes 4.

On the other hand, `--rcheck` would not have increased the hitcount, so it would have been increased only by `--set` once, and then checked by each following rule:

- for no previous hits -- same as before ;
- for one previous hit -- set increases the recent hitcount, and we are stopped ; the resulting recent hitcount is 2.

---

In conclusion -- I would probably go as follows:

- use `--set` *after* `--update` or `--rcheck` ;
- use `--rcheck` for LOG rules ;
- use `--update` for DROP/ACCEPT/RETURN rules .

Hope that helps.